# New line characters issue in Tweet Content

Tags: java, twitter, newline

I am trying to read tweet contents from my DB and write into a .csv file. However, some of the tweets have newline characters, so that is why; the csv file seems weird when I open it. 
Could you please help me about how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Please specify how you read the contents if the tweets and write to CSV.

Comment: //This is reading part 

ResultSet rsForSelectTweetContentsQuery = null;
String selectTweetContentsQuery = "SELECT tweetContent FROM filteredtweets WHERE originalTweetId = 4515415454654";

String tweetContent = rsForSelectTweetContentsQuery.getString("tweetContent");

//Thisis writing part
try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(csvFileWriter))
        {
            bufferedWriter.write(tweetId + "," + tweetContent);
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
            
            bufferedWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {            
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
//This is reading part 

ResultSet rsForSelectTweetContentsQuery = null;
String selectTweetContentsQuery = "SELECT tweetContent FROM filteredtweets WHERE originalTweetId = 4515415454654";

String tweetContent = rsForSelectTweetContentsQuery.getString("tweetContent");

//Thisis writing part
try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(csvFileWriter))
        {
            bufferedWriter.write(tweetId + "," + tweetContent);
            bufferedWriter.newLine();

            bufferedWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Everybody thinks that CSV files are trivial, but that is actually far from the case.  The CSV format has a [formal specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), and covers cases like:

- Comma itself is a value
- A quoted string itself contains quotes
- A value has new-lines
- Unicode values
- etc.

Basically, you *don't* want to write this yourself, you'll get it wrong.  Use [this library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csv4180/).